# Use form to complete array

Tags: javascript

So I got `console.log(show);` to print out the data attribute from my form as such array = {}

How can I change the const states array so it takes the show variable and appends it as an array as I have it hard coded.

Comment: *"How can I change the const states array..."* **`const` does not change directly, use `let` or clone the array.** *"...so it takes the show variable and appends it as an array as I have it hard coded."* **Huh...er...wuat!?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getAttribute()` to get the value of `data-states` and then use regex to select individual values.

```js
const states = [
    "CA",
    "IL",
    "MO"
];

let data_states =  document.getElementById('concatForm').getAttribute('data-states').match(/\w{1,}/g);

data_states.forEach( (state,i) => states[i] = state );

console.log( states );
```

```html
<form id="concatForm" class="needs-validation" data-states="['AL','AZ','CA']" ></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [conact](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) function

```
const show = ['AL','AZ','CA'];
const states = [
    "CA",
    "IL",
    "MO"
];

console.log(states.concat(show));
// ["CA","IL","MO","AL","AZ","CA"]
```

Comment: So instead of hard coding the values into states as shown above, how can I make `const states` create an array out of the variable show.

Comment: I don't want to use the values I have right now inside states, I can delete those .. I want it to be `const states = [ Array of show ]`